# Yesod: how do I serve dynamically-generated CSS?

Tags: css, yesod

OK, so my handlers for HTML are of type `Handler RepHtml`.  I also see `RepXml`, `RepJson`, and `RepPlain`.  How do I serve CSS, or Javascript for that matter?

The closest I can get, if this is close, is `$(luciusFile "template.lucius")`, but this expands to something with type `CssUrl <Foundation>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send just a lonely css or javascript file then I guess you could just create RepCss and RepJS types like so:

```
import Yesod.Content

newtype RepCss = RepCss Content
instance HasReps RepCss where
    chooseRep (RepCss c) _ = return (typeCss, c)
```

You could also create functions:

```
luciusToContent :: CssUrl (Route master) -> GHandler sub master Content
```

and

```
luciusToRepCss :: CssUrl (Route master) -> GHandler sub master RepCss
```

in the same manner as functions `hamletToContent` and `hamletToRepHtml` are defined in module `Yesod.Handler` and use them to create the output from the lucius file